# Scala parser failure handling, dangling commas

Tags: parsing, scala, error-handling

Getting started with Scala parser combinations, before moving on need to grasp failure/error handling better (note: still getting into Scala as well)

Want to parse strings like "a = b, c = d" into a list of tuples but flag the user when dangling commas are found.

Thought about matching off failure ("a = b, ") when matching comma separated property assignments:

```
 def commaList[T](inner: Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]] =
   rep1sep(inner, ",") | rep1sep(inner, ",") ~> opt(",") ~> failure("Dangling comma")

 def propertyAssignment: Parser[(String, String)] = ident ~ "=" ~ ident ^^ {
   case id ~ "=" ~ prop => (id, prop)
 }
```

And call the parser with:

```
 p.parseAll(p.commaList(p.propertyAssignment), "name = John , ")
```

which results in a Failure, no surprise but with:

```
 string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but end of source found
```

The commList function succeeds on the first property assignment and starts repeating given the comma but the next "ident" fails on the fact that the next character is the end of the source data.  Thought I could catch that 2nd alternative in the commList would match:

```
 rep1sep(inner, ",") ~> opt(",") ~> failure("Dangling comma")
```

Nix.  Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalaz to the rescue :-)

When you are working with warnings, it is not a good idea to exit your parser with a failure. You can easily combine the parser with the Scalaz writer monad. With this monads you can add messages to the partial result during the parser run. These messages could be infos, warnings or errors. After the parser finishes, you can then validate the result, if it can be used or if it contains critical problems. With such a separate vaildator step you get usual much better error messages. For example you could accept arbitrary characters at the end of the string, but issue an error when they are found (e.g. "Garbage found after last statement"). The error message can be much more helpful for the user than the cryptic default one you get in the example below ("string matching regex `\z' expected [...]").

Here is an example based on the code in your question:

```
    scala> :paste
    // Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    import util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
    import scalaz._, Scalaz._

    object DemoParser extends RegexParsers {
      type Warning = String
      case class Equation(left : String, right : String)
      type PWriter = Writer[Vector[Warning], List[Equation]]
      val emptyList : List[Equation] = Nil

      def rep1sep2[T](p : => Parser[T], q : => Parser[Any]): Parser[List[T]] =
        p ~ rep(q ~> p) ^^ {case x~y => x::y}


      def name : Parser[String] = """\w+""".r
      def equation : Parser[Equation] = name ~ "=" ~ name ^^ { case n ~ _ ~ v => Equation(n,v) }
      def commaList : Parser[PWriter] = rep1sep(equation, ",") ^^ (_.set(Vector()))
      def danglingComma  : Parser[PWriter] = opt(",") ^^ (
         _ map (_ => emptyList.set(Vector("Warning: Dangling comma")))
                 getOrElse(emptyList.set(Vector("getOrElse(emptyList.set(Vector(""))))
      def danglingList : Parser[PWriter] =  commaList ~ danglingComma ^^ {
        case l1 ~ l2 => (l1.over ++ l2.over).set(l1.written ++ l2.written) }

      def apply(input: String): PWriter = parseAll(danglingList, input) match {
        case Success(result, _) => result
        case failure : NoSuccess => emptyList.set(Vector(failure.msg))
      }
    }

    // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

    import util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers
    import scalaz._
    import Scalaz._
    defined module DemoParser

    scala> DemoParser("a=1, b=2")
    res2: DemoParser.PWriter = (Vector(),List(Equation(a,1), Equation(b,2)))

    scala> DemoParser("a=1, b=2,")
    res3: DemoParser.PWriter = (Vector(Warning: Dangling comma),List(Equation(a,1), Equation(b,2)))

    scala> DemoParser("a=1, b=2, ")
    res4: DemoParser.PWriter = (Vector(Warning: Dangling comma),List(Equation(a,1), Equation(b,2)))

    scala> DemoParser("a=1, b=2, ;")
    res5: DemoParser.PWriter = (Vector(string matching regex `\z' expected but `;' found),List())

    scala>
```

As you can see, it handles the error cases fine. If you want to extend the example, add case classes for different kinds of errors and include the current parser positions in the messages.

Btw. the problem with the white spaces is handled by the `RegexParsers` class. If you want to change the handling of white spaces, just override the field `whiteSpace`.

Comment: thanks for the Scalaz tip.  Will play around with the library.

Answer (score 1):

Your parser isn't expecting the trailing whitespace at the end of `"name = John , "`.

You could use a regex to optionally parse `","` followed by any amount of whitespace:

```
def commaList[T](inner: Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]] =
  rep1sep(inner, ",") <~ opt(",\\s*".r ~> failure("Dangling comma"))
```

Note that you can avoid using alternatives (`|`) here, by making the failure part of the optional parser. If the optional part consumes some input and then fails, then the whole parser fails.